# Onclick function doesn't work for calling javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have try this on jsfiddle,

here's the html :

```
<input onclick="masuk(10);" type="radio" name="myRadio1" value="Yes"/>1<br/>
<input onclick="alert(10);" type="radio" name="myRadio1" value="Yes"/>2<br/>
```

here's the js :

```
function masuk(a) {
  alert(a);
}
```

here's the link : http://jsfiddle.net/codingsolver/MsYqx/

the point is, why if click the first radio button which call function masuk() it doesn't want to show the alert. But if I directly call the alert, it works. Does any one know why?? Thanks lots

Comment: sorry if the html appear like that, i hope you can directly check the jsfiddle, thanks

Comment: Your code (here) and your fiddle don't match. Why is that? The fiddle should demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Excuse me but in your give jsFiddle link the code is working as you want. Can you please double check your question? Thanks.

Comment: I really didnt get your question

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Make sure you are loading javascript after the DOM has been loaded. Place javascript above `</body>`

Answer (score 0):

Your jsFiddle is gone, but in order to call from HTML like that, your variable would have to be globally defined, which it probably isn't (but can't say for sure without the full source).